# Why we can use Spot Instances for the EMR cluster in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-emr

I came across this question in my AWS practice and like to post it here for further discussion:

> Your company is
>   planning on using the EMR service available in AWS for running their
>   big data framework and wants to minimize the cost for running the EMR
>   service. Which of the following could help achieve this?

```
Options:
A.  Running the EMR cluster in a dedicated VPC
B.  Choosing Spot Instances for the underlying nodes
C.  Choosing On-Demand Instances for the underlying nodes
D.  Disable automated backups 

Correct Answer
B. Choosing Spot Instances for the underlying nodes
```

Question:
quoted from [AWS document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/how-spot-instances-work.html): *When you use Spot Instances, you must be prepared for interruptions.*

My understanding to the EMR service is it requires resources to complete the job (service), if say a mapreduce job is not given enough resource, the job will fail.
Spot instance, though the cost is low, it doesn't guarantee the availability, AWS states very clearly (quoted here from the same page):

> If your maximum price exceeds the current Spot price for the specified
>   instance, and capacity is available, your request is fulfilled
>   immediately.

Note: "*capacity is available*", in another word, **if capacity is NOT available**, **your request won't get fulfilled.**

I think On-Demand instances is what should be chosen for the underlying nodes, get the job is more important than saving cost, it is meaningless if the job cannot be done.

Comment: The customer wants to minimize the cost and never mentioned the availability. And this is off-topic for SO.

Comment: Thanks. If by minimizing the cost could lead to job failure, I highly doubt if that is an acceptable way to save cost.

Comment: It depends on the service. For a short data transfer job or analyzing job would take several hours and that is suitable to use spot not on-demand even though there is a probability of the service failure. Furthermore, you can mix the on-demand and spot to preserve the service availiability, so the spot is the key.

Comment: Thank you, I like your idea of mixing Spot with On-Demand, I think it is more suitable and feasible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS certification exam keeps throwing these kinds of googly.

Since it's not mentioned that the company doesn't want any interruptions, `Spot` instance is the right answer to minimize cost.

And from my experience `Spot` gives up to 80% discount compared to that of `on-demand` cost.

Comment: Thank you for having the same feeling of "googly" comment on AWS exam